# After update to Kernel 4.10 wifi breaks down after 20 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel

I am dualbooting my Microsoft Surface Pro4 into Ubuntu. I had to update to kernel 4.10. as this seemed the only solution to a freeze issue, so downgrading my kernel is not an option. Now after about 20 seconds after boot, my wifi disconnects and is unable to reconnect.

As i am new to Linux, please tell me what commands to put in to generate additional information.

Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

this:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lsusb:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:090c Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1286:204c Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, which version?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Done. What should i add now

Comment: This device `1286:204c` has not been added to Linux yet. Did it work with a previous kernel?

Comment: In 4.4. i did not experience issues with the internet connectivity but did not check the "lsusb" command if it was connected. 

The 4.4. kernel lead to irregular freezes of the system, where the upgrade on 4.10. appeared to be the fix to.

Is this device crucial for internet connectivity?

Comment: This is your wireless device.

Comment: Irregularly wihout any change it does work for hours. Also it works for a few couple of minutes at each startup. So since it hasnt been added to Linux, i assume there is nothing i can do, as to hope for an update with a fix?